# Recommendation system NLP ideas

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp, word-embeddings, text-classification

**The problem**:

If we have a clustering problem with lets say x groups. And each group has a document describing it, lets say 3 pages. Then we have n observations each with a smaller piece of text describing it, 1 or 2 sentences.
And we want to allocate these observations to one of the groups.

**Ideas**:

What would be a good technique to use for this problem. Would creating text embeddings for the larger and smaller pieces of text, and then computing their similarities be reasonable?

And if so are there any text embedding techniques you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating text embeddings for the larger and smaller pieces of text and then computing their similarities can indeed be a reasonable approach.

**Text Embedding Techniques**

There are several text embedding techniques that can be used for this purpose. Some common techniques include:

**Word2Vec** represents words as high-dimensional vectors, capturing semantic relationships between words based on their context in a given corpus.

**GloVe** (Global Vectors for Word Representation) is an unsupervised learning algorithm for obtaining vector representations for words, which captures global statistics of the corpus.

**BERT** (Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers) is a transformer-based model that generates contextualized word embeddings, taking into account the surrounding words in a sentence.

In your case BERT seems to be the most appropriate technique for this problem since it generates contextualized word embeddings, taking into account the surrounding words in a sentence. This contextual understanding is crucial for capturing the nuanced meanings and relationships within the larger documents and the smaller pieces of text.